# BNF to create vectors with same lengths

Tags: grammar, bnf

Is it possible to describe in BNF a pair of vectors of the same length? For instance, I would like to use such a grammar to capture valid dot product operations as such an operation requires vectors of the same length.

I can describe one vector (I think this is okay): [1,2,3]

```
<vector> ::= "[" <vectorItems> "]"
<vectorItems> ::= <wholeNumber>|<wholeNumber>","<vectorItems>
```

But how can I describe the following (that is, the vectors can be of any length but the lengths of the two vectors are the same; Is this even possible? I am kind of new at this)?: [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  S := [T]
  T := N,T,N | N],[N
  N := (any valid number)

  Nonterminals: S, T, N
  Terminals: [ ] , # (anything required by your definition of N)
```

The strings in this language are, in order from smallest to largest, where N stands for an arbitrary number:

L = { **[N],[N]**, **[N,N],[N,N]**, **[N,N,N],[N,N,N]**, ...}

= {aBcDe | a=**[** and c=**],[** and e=**]** and B=(**N,**)^k **N** and D=(**N,**)^k **N** 
and k > 0)

(terminal symbols shown in bold)

Comment: Nice! Although if the OP wants to implement this using a parser generator, it will be a bit troublesome to separate the two vectors, in which case it's IMO better to simply match 2 vectors and at a later stage check the sizes of the two vectors. But again: very nice solution!

Comment: Very nice solution indeed! I sat back for a minute to dwell in its elegance. Thank you!

Comment: @Justin, if this answered your question, you can accept it as such (see the check-mark at the left hand side of the answer).